# EMR S3 : FileDeletedInMetadataNotFoundException: File is marked as deleted in the metadata

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I try to run a hadoop job which creates, copies, deletes files on S3 and reads these files from S3 when required.

My job intermittently fails with following exception to which I am looking for a permanent fix or workaround. The exception is:

> Caused by:   com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.consistency.exception.FileDeletedInMetadataNotFoundException: File '' is marked as deleted in the metadata

When I run the command `emrfs diff` externally after the job fails, the outpout has `MANIFEST_ONLY` files in red color.

Then I run command `emrfs sync` which removes these files and then my job runs with no error.

I do not want to debug after the job fails as that is not acceptable for me. Also I do not want any manual intervention to make sure that my jobs runs seamlessly.

My job itself creates, copies, deletes files and then is not able to read it which seems to be confusing and I haven't been able to find out any solution in the documentation.

Would appreciate all the relevant suggestions.